# common Settings.settings file for entire solution

Tags: c#, properties, settings

Is there a way to have common Properties file for all the projects of the solution?

I have a console application and bunch of other class librarry files and i want to have only one Settings file for them.

I am not talking about app.Config file. I am talking about Settings.settings file.

Any idea how i can do it?

Also is it a good practice to store configuration settings in the Settings file rather than app.config?

Comment: I would think that would ruin the whole solution/project idea. You can create multiple projects for one solution to easily reproduce parts of your code in other solutions. Projects are not a way to organize a solution - for that you would be best off with folders inside a project.

Comment: The contents from the settings.settings file generates the contents of the app.config file which is unique to each solution.  Unless you have application ( not user ) settings for your class library files your design will very quickly show some design flaws.  I strongly suggest you avoid the configuration file if you are dealing with multiple solutions that generate a single project.

Comment: did i say i have multiple solutions that generate single project? All i want to do is have common Settings.setting file across the project. Just like we have web.config or app.config.

Comment: app.config is not normally saved and web.config is an different animal.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Place the file you want to share across projects in a Solution Folder. Then, in each project, choose to Add Existing Item ..

In the Add Existing Item dialog, choose the common file. Instead of clicking the Add button, click the drop-down arrow on the right side of the Add button and choose Add As Link from the drop-down menu.

[image: Add As Link]

If this is for a Settings file, you need to set the Custom Tool property for the file:

[image: file properties]

If your file is `Settings.settings` you can open your project properties and go to the Settings tab and Visual Studio will set this Custom Tool property for you automatically.

Once the Custom Tool is set, you will see a Designer.cs file created underneath your settings file.  This Designer.cs file contains generated code to make your settings accessible programatically.

[image: Designer sub-file]

As you can see, the Designer.cs file is also a linked file, and it's physical location will be the same as your settings file.

Comment: but then if i try to access them like Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName in the class library, it doesnt recognize it.

Comment: If this solves your problem (it should) upvoting and accepting my answer would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I will upvote and accept your answer after i try the solution. give me some time.

Comment: As mentioned by Luis below, you probably also need to set the "Custom Tool Namespace" to avoid visual studio generating the .cs file with a wrong namespace.

Comment: What if you have a Web application (ASP.NET MVC) and you want configuration to override app.config classes in the referenced class libraries of same solution?

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, you can set the **Settings** to `public` instead of `internal`.

Go to YourProject->Properties->Settings

[image]

Comment: Never noticed that Access Modifier dropdown at the very top of the screen, almost invisible with its black background (using my Visual Studio "dark" theme). Great tip!

Answer (score 2):

The answer accepted above by @quentin-starin is correct, but I had a situation where specifying the CustomToolNamespace came in handy as I already had some project specific settings.  By setting the Namespace to something specific, I did not get the autogenerated namespace relative to each project in the solution.