# cross assemblies settings file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, settings.settings

I have n solution with multiple runnable (exe) projects (WPF and Console) and multiple class libraries.
I'm looking for a way to have a single settings file cross all the dll's and exe projects.

Is there any good way to achieve this using the existing .NET settings files?

Comment: are you looking to use [Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes, but I want to consume those settings from the class libraries as well

Comment: do all of these runnables reside in the same Sln / Project..?

Comment: then this is what you want then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792997/common-settings-settings-file-for-entire-solution

Comment: it's amazing what a `google search` yields