# Saving the settings in the settings designer generates a wrong namespace in the Designer.cs file

Tags: visual-studio, application-settings

Beforehand I renamed the settings file to AppSettings.settings. Then I added links to that file to my other projects in the solution, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792997/common-settings-settings-file-for-entire-solution).

This is really weird. After saving a setting I have to either change the namespace manually or I run the custom tool (right click on AppSettings.settings > Run Custom Tool) which also corrects it. So the custom tool seems to work fine.

Any ideas?

Btw: The project in question is my startup project. In its properties it has the correct namespace.

Comment: Well, pretty bad advice, doomed to go wrong.  There is now more than one way to edit the settings.  Which ever project's settings you edited will set the their root namespace to the properties.  Either give all projects the same root namespace or be sure to also set the Custom Tool Namespace property to the same value on *all* the Settings.settings project items.  Or just don't do this since it is so horribly brittle, very easy to not get a project's Designer.cs file re-generated and for the app.config file to get out of sync.

Comment: @HansPassant: The "Custom Tool Namespace" property was the answer. I don't know how I missed it. It was right beneath the "Custom Tool" property.

I'm curious. Do you know a better way to share one Settings.settings file across multiple projects in one solution?