# How to share AssemblyInfo, Resources and Settings between multiple projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, properties, projects-and-solutions

I need to share Properties (AssemblyInfo, Resources and Settings) between many multiple projects inside my solution in order to decrease repetition. Projects will likely be used in other solutions, so code dependency must be minimal to allow for easy transfer.

The top method for sharing AssemblyInfo seems to be creating a solution-level "SharedAssemblyInfo.cs" file, which is linked by each project, meaning only one file exists. However it is more difficult to create shared Resources and Settings as their given designers cannot be transferred into a Solution-level folder or Shared Project.

What would be the best practice to share Project Properties within a solution in a uniform fashion, and what disadvantages of using the proposed answer be?

Comment: You can create Resources and settings in Common project, and reference it everywhere... as for AssemblyInfo, right, keeping one file, and linking it everywhere should work

Comment: There are ways to do it with all files in a common location.  I don't have much experience doing so myself, but I found this other stack overflow answer that may be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792997/common-settings-settings-file-for-entire-solution